# AWS S3 notificationConfiguration throws Unable to validate the following destination configurations (Service: Amazon S3)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, events, amazon-s3, amazon-sns

I have created the AWS S3 and SNS via java SDK. Now I am trying to set event for the created S3 bucket. The following is my code snippet

```
private void createS3Event(String snsTopicARN) {
    AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client();
    BucketNotificationConfiguration notificationConfiguration = new BucketNotificationConfiguration();
    TopicConfiguration topicConfiguration = new TopicConfiguration(snsTopicARN, EnumSet.of(S3Event.ObjectCreated));
    notificationConfiguration.addConfiguration("snsTopicConfig", topicConfiguration);

    String bucketName = "test-bucket";

    s3Client.setBucketNotificationConfiguration(bucketName, notificationConfiguration);
}
```

}

But the above code throws the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Unable to validate the following destination configurations (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidArgument; Request ID: 40F2EB4DB807BD38), S3 Extended Request ID: Cr3P1AZ4FuqHr2UrYBUc5U28uDNh4pWAtqGIRYgDlQsQ5VT4eJ4XK5z0BKdannipxRnEtLyi8jM=
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1389)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:902)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:607)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:376)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:338)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:287)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3826)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.setBucketNotificationConfiguration(AmazonS3Client.java:2240)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.setBucketNotificationConfiguration(AmazonS3Client.java:2216)
```

How to get this to work using java api?

Answer (score -1):

I have similar problems using python SDK. When you set a event on s3 to trigger SNS, you need add permission on SNS to allow s3 to trigger it. I did not see doing so in your code.
I am sorry I did not familiar with java SDK, i do not know what exactly needs to be added, but adding permission on SNS should be the right direction.